# App login, why do users need to login?

Tags: login, user-centered-design, app

I was browsing a [nice restaurant finder app called Zomato](https://www.zomato.com/) recently. However the first page is a login screen which is bad in my opinion, it does have a skip login at top although not immediately noticeable.

Why does an app like this need a login? What is the benefit to the user? Can the data not be save locally for things like favourites (games seem to do ok without login)? I'm sure there must be a technical reason we have to login, anyone able to enlighten me? 
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Logins help for a couple reasons, I don't know the app personally so I will answer in general:

1. Persistence of data, if the user changes phones or goes on to the desktop version of the website they will still have their search history, favorites, etc.
2. Community, some apps like to put faces behind the data, would you rather take restaurant recommendations from me or Gordon Ramsey, accounts give a way to bring people together and put faces to names.
3. Moderation, people are more accountable for their actions if they have a well cultivated account on the line. Sure in this case they can proceed without one or start a new one but all of those refined searches, settings, and relationships they built through that account will be lost.

Comment: Thanks for this. A good answer, I figured it would be something like this. Certainly the community aspect for shared reviews and the like. I do think however that it should not be the first screen you see. I found an interesting article here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/StartingStopping.html and one from Nielsen Norman here: http://www.nngroup.com/articles/login-walls/

Comment: I agree, I would only present login walls as the first screen in applications like Facebook where all interaction comes down to being logged in. I suppose that company just has logging in users as a high priority.

Answer (score 1):

@DasBeasto: Has answered well. However I would like to add Business owner's perspective.

1. They would like to gather demographic data to analyze and improve
   its performance.
2. Sending promotional offers for specific groups, if needed.
3. Get sales revenue analytics based on data collected. (Sale can be from ad campaigning too)

Comment: Thanks @Muks. I knew that login had big benefits for the company behind the app just wasn't sure how it helped the user. I guess with an app the benefit is that you only have to login once. They usually stay logged in after that.

Comment: @Kris: For your question, then I would say its part of government or country's regulation at times to not to save credentials on any device more than 20 minutes, this was what I experienced while working for a government application.